# FogBugz API - Change OrderBy direction

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'm getting a list of cases fro the FogBugz API and the OrderBy clause is 'case'. This is getting the first X items I request, where I want to get the last X items. How can I change the direction of the order by?

I've tried:

```
OrderByDir:desc
OrderBy:case desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the non-obvious:

```
orderby:"-case"
```